# Closing function in a VB.NET console application

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application, exit, exit-code

How can I fire off a function when it detects the console closing when using `Environment.Exit(0)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is probably to handle the [`AppDomain.ProcessExit` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx), which is raised when the application's parent process exits.

For example:

```
Module MyApp

    Sub Main()
        ' Attach the event handler method
        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit, AddressOf MyApp_ProcessExit

        ' Do something
        ' ...

        Environment.Exit(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyApp_ProcessExit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("App Is Exiting...")
    End Sub

End Module
```

But calling `Environment.Exit` may not be the best solution to your original problem. In general, [the only time it is necessary to use this method is when there might be other foreground threads running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692371/366904). And in that case, it's worth investigating ways of gracefully terminating those other threads without resorting to draconian measures that kill the entire process.

`Environment.Exit`, despite the somewhat pleasant-sounding name, is a pretty brutal measure. It's not quite as bad as clicking "End Task" in the Windows Task Manager (and note that if you do *that*, the `ProcessExit` event will not be raised, meaning that the above suggestion will not work), but it's probably not the solution you really want, either.