# How to detect application close when no form is present (console application)

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, windows-7

I've been wondering about this for a while.

I currently want an application to detect when it is being closed. The tricky thing is, this application is a console one meaning there is no form close event or like-wise.

I had a scout on google and really only came up with the code below which detects only shutting down, logging off and not specifically application closing.

ShutdownEvents Code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    AddHandler (SystemEvents.SessionEnding), AddressOf ShutDown.OnShuttingdown
    AddHandler (SystemEvents.SessionEnded), AddressOf ShutDown.OnShutdown
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Public Class ShutDown
    Public Shared Sub OnShuttingdown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SessionEndingEventArgs)
        e.Cancel = True 'only set if you turn down the shutdown request
        Console.WriteLine("Shutting down - Reason is " & e.Reason)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub OnShutdown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SessionEndedEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Shutdown - Reason is " & e.Reason)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Class
End Module
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a console control handler. There is no facility for doing that in the `Console` class, but you can call Windows API functions to do it. An example in C# is at [Detecting Process Exit From Console Application in C#](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrnat/archive/2004/09/23/11594.aspx).

You'll want to read and understand the [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function.

I wrote a couple of articles a few years ago about using the Windows Console API from C#. Unfortunately, DevSource seems to have lost the one that describes this. The other two are available at

http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Working-with-Console-Screen-Buffers-in-NET/

and

http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Console-Input-in-NET/

Full source for the code presented in those articles is available at http://mischel.com/pubs/consoledotnet.zip.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but I really am not going to delve into winapi for this application.

Answer (score 0):

Try an AddHandler for [AppDomain.ProcessExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx)

e.g. via [Thread.GetDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.getdomain.aspx)

Comment: if you like a windows api solution instead of a .net approach, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317082/how-to-close-console-application-gracefully-on-windows-shutdown

Comment: I'll look into this method. Might be worthwhile.